# How to separate positive and negative numbers into their own columns?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with the following columns and data:

```
activity_dt | activity_amt
 2009-01-01 |   -500
 2009-01-01 |    750
```

Can I write a query that looks at the sign of `activity_amt` and puts it in the credits column if it's positive, and the debits column if it's negative? (I'm using Sybase)

```
activity_dt | debits | credits
 2009-01-01 |  -500  |   750
```

Comment: Most accounting systems avoid negative numbers in the database. They have two fields: amount which is always positive and a flag field for whether the transaction is a debit or credit.

Comment: Yep- I am aware of that.

Comment: nice question n solved me a lot of problems. just in passing did u notice that when u add a positive percentage to a negative percentage the net doesnt square off... if an asset goes up 100% and goes down 50% they are at the same price point.. i hope u get what i mean.. so it kinda calls for a case statement for adding negative numbers to positive numbers and hence one more reason to always stay positive !!!!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
select activity_dt, 
    sum(case when activity_amt < 0 then activity_amt else 0 end) as debits, 
    sum(case when activity_amt > 0 then activity_amt else 0 end) as credits
from the_table
group by activity_dt
order by activity_dt
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for being quick on the draw.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the exact syntax in Sybase, but you should be able to group on the date and sum up the positive and negative values:

```
select
  activity_dt,
  sum(case when activity_amt < 0 then activity_amt else 0 end) as debits,
  sum(case when activity_amt >= 0 then activity_amt else 0 end) as credits
from
  theTable
group by
  activity_dt
```

Comment: For symmetry, you could use '<' and '>' without any trauma - the zeroes will be counted as zeroes...

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, in this case. I make an active choise to use the complementing operators so that all records are included, in case this example would be used for something slightly different. :)

Comment: thanks jon ! ya but how r u so sure that if u leave the 0 out the record will be counted, in this case it makes sense cos u r just adding up a 0 but then this simple select could could actually involve a variation from a mean as in sum(case when activity_amt >0 then activity_amt = activity_amt - MEAN_OF_A_SET_OF_NUMBERS else ....... symmetrically i wud do case when amt>0, case when amt<0 and case when amt=0 and case when amt is NULL.. it always makes sense to first take the boundary conditions out of the equation, little more code, little more clocks but u get home with the shirt !

Comment: @user1974729: You can sum up more things if you like, but the OP only asked about the positive and negative amounts.

Comment: full credit to u for pointing out that 0 will be counted and NULL wont be counted at all. it takes a lot of experience to figure that out.im forever confused with the boundary conditions of 0,NULL cos they always come back to hurt me and so i recommended the usage of the 0 statement seperately for users like me and not advanced users like u who have it covered..

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select JV_GroupsHead.GroupTitle
         from JV_GroupsHead
         whereJV_GroupsHead.Id=jv.GroupId) as 'GroupName'
        ,jv.Revenue
        ,jv.AccountNo
        ,jv.AccountNoTitle
        ,(case when jv.Revenue  < 0 then jv.Revenue  else 0 end) as 'debits'
        ,(case when jv.Revenue> 0 then jv.Revenue  else 0 end) as 'credits'
from JVFunction1('2010-07-08','2010-08-08') as jv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a new answer to this problem using the `DECODE` function. 
I hope this turns out to be useful for everyone.

```
select activity_dt, 
sum((DECODE(activity_amt /-ABS(activity_amt), 1, activity_amt, 0))) as credits,
sum((DECODE(activity_amt /-ABS(activity_amt), -1, activity_amt, 0))) as debits
from the_table
group by activity_dt
order by activity_dt;
```